# Iterating through 2 Dimensional Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Here's my problem. I wish to iterate over rows specified by start and length variables (both a integer values). However, the following code gives me a segmentation fault. How do I specify the rows through which I wish to iterate over?

(Pls note: I only want the values at each row (notice *j is being accessed) If there is a better way, do let me know.. )

```
vector<int>::iterator j;
vector< vector<int> >::iterator i;
vector< vector<int> > twoD;
vector<double> A;

for(i = (twoD.begin() + 1 + start); i != (twoD.begin() + start + 1 + length); i++)
    for(j = (*i).begin(); j !=(*i).end(); j++)
        printf(" %d  \n", *j);
```

The same code, without specifying the start and end rows (the start and start+length parameters in the for loop) compiles and runs as expected.

```
for(i = (twoD.begin() + 1); i != twoD.end(); i++)
    for(j = (*i).begin(); j !=(*i).end(); j++)
        printf(" %d  \n", *j);
```

Comment: Why are you adding 1 to `start` and `length`?

Comment: Where is the seg-fault?  Have you checked the values of `*j`?

Comment: So work it through on paper and find out where you go out of bounds. Easy.

Comment: The number of rows in A[] is exactly equal to the number of rows in  twoD. Technically, this shouldn't go out of bounds at all.

Comment: Also, *j is not greater than the number of rows in A either.

Comment: I'm wondering if we are allowed to add start and length and any such integer parameters to the iterator. Is that part alright? Anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If the integers in your two-dimensional array are greater than or equal to the size of your double vector A, you will try to access an out-of-bounds index.

In other words, if this is ever the case:  `*j >= A.size()`, you'll go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

After a few for loops, your "i" will be greater than twoD. This means you will run out of bounds.
Never call this:

```
i != (twoD.begin() + start + 1 + length)
```

Instead just type like this:

```
i != (twoD.end)
```

Also do not use i++. Instead just use ++i. It's a bit safer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want it to run only from row - start to row - start+length. (I'm adding 1 because I don't want the contents of row 0.) Hence, twoD.end() is not an option.